# Wordpress add custom search

Tags: php, page-template

I create template customsearch.php, adding this for page example.com\search.html (ID page: 18)

```
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: CustomSearch
    */
    
    get_header(); ?>
    
    <div id="primary">
            <div id="content">
        
    <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=000000000000000000000:uiyuiyiyiuyui"></script>
    <div class="gcse-search"></div>
</div>
</div>
    
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How to this page adding for example.com?q=xxxxxx

Result:

```
example.com/?s=xxxxxx - default search wordpress

example.com/?q=xxxxxx - google custom search
```

Sorry for my English

P.S.

I want to keep a default search

Comment: So all you need to do is add this new URL format, so that `?q=x` goes to your new search page?

Comment: Yes, to search from the search.html script